# How to pass InforProps that extends RouteComponentProps<{ id: string}> in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've just begun to write React test code in TypeScript,

**[Login.test.tsx]**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Login from './Login';

describe('Login', () => {
    const login = shallow(<Login  />);
 
});
```

and an error `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<ILoginInfoProps>'` showed up.

I figured that I'd need to set default values for the props in `Login` component, which would be a type of `ILoginInfoProps` defined as below.

**[ILoginInfoProps.interface.ts]**

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export default interface ILoginInfoProps extends RouteComponentProps<{ id: string}>{

}
```

I tried to set the default value like the following, but it doesn't compile...

**[Login.tsx]**

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginInfo from '../interfaces/LoginInfo.interface';
import ILoginInfoProps from '../interfaces/ILoginInfoProps.interface';
import ILoginInfoState from '../interfaces/ILoginInfoState.interface';

class Login extends React.Component<ILoginInfoProps, ILoginInfoState>{

  public static defaultProps: ILoginInfoProps = {
    id: '24'
  };  
.......
.......
```

It says `Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ILoginInfoProps'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'ILoginInfoProps'.`

How can I set a default value so that it won't cause an error in the test code file?

**UPDATE**

What I've tried...

```
class Login extends React.Component<ILoginInfoProps, ILoginInfoState>{

  public static defaultProps: ILoginInfoProps = {
    match: {
      id: '24';
    }
  };
```

```
class Login extends React.Component<ILoginInfoProps, ILoginInfoState>{

  public static defaultProps: ILoginInfoProps = {
    match: {
      id: string;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please use the comment section only when you ask me for more background info about my question. When you answer my question, please post an answer with a code snippet as a concrete example, instead of just writing one line comment like "Just use XXX and the problem will be solved. " in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it's causing an error is that you are missing some fields when you define
`ILoginInfoProps` in your code.
The missing fields are `history, match, location` because the `interface ILoginInfoProps` that you define extends `RouteComponentProps<{}>`.

So you should try this.

```
public static defaultProps: ILoginInfoProps = {
    id: '24',
    history: undefined,
    location: undefined, 
    match: undefined
};
```

Also, if you want to actually use one of the missing fields somewhere in your code, for example `this.props.history.push('/')`, just passing the `Login` component like

```
const login = shallow(<Login  />);
```

isn't going to take you anywhere. Instead, wrap the `Login` component like

```
<Route exact path = "/login" component = {Login}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RouteComponentProps<{ id: string}>` equals to

```
{
    match: {
        id: string;
    }
}
```

if you want to do `{id: string}` your declaration should be

```
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';

export default interface ILoginInfoProps extends RouteComponentProps<{}>{
    id: string;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated the declaration exactly as shown in your answer, and then updated the Login component (see the "UPDATE" part at the bottom of my original post), but for some reason it didn't work...  I got an error ```Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'match<{}>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'match<{}>'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(76, 5): The expected type comes from property 'match' which is declared here on type 'ILoginInfoProps'```